# Category information of an Activity through ActivityInfo class

Tags: android, android-activity, categories

I was expecting to see Categories that a particular Activity
belongs to in ActivityInfo class but I could not find any
reference to Category in the ActivityInfo class.  Anybody
knows where Category information is maintained for an Activity?

Comment: I have this same problem. It is especially a problem if you are trying to get information about all packages including ones that may be disabled since those don't show up in `queryIntentActivities()` or `resolveActivity()`.

Answer (score 2):

Activities do not have categories. Intent filters have categories. I don't see where you can readily find the `IntentFilters` for a given `ActivityInfo`, but you can get the `IntentFilter` from a `ResolveInfo`, and you get those via `queryIntentActivities()` and `resolveActivity()`.